# Trying to render a specific username and a list of all the usernames on same page

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using Node.js, Express, Handlebars and trying to make an interface to manage user's roles and display a list of all the user names and I have a login button that changes to the username of the current user logged in but when I call my user.js model with `user: user` only displays all users but the current logged in username is not displayed and if I use the `user: req.user` it only shows the current user logged in.
how do I go about doing both on the same page?

here is my code

```
router.get('/', LogingCheck, roleAuth, (req, res, next) => {
    User.find((err, user) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else {
            res.render('admin/index', { title: 'Role Manager', user: user, });
        }
    });
});
```

I then call the username for the current user  like so `{{user.username}}` then call the list of usernames like so `{{this.username}}`

Comment: If you have two different values to render you will need two different variables to reference them. Perhaps `currentUser` and `allUsers`?

Comment: fixed it but I'm unsure of what the actual problem was @76484

here's what I did:  res.render('admin/index', { title: 'Role Manager', users: users, user: req.user });

Comment: You cannot set both your list of users (`user: user`) _and_ your current user (`user: req.user`) to the `user` variable. You need two variables, as you have done with `users` and `user`.